# replace double quotes with back slash double quotes in shell script

Tags: shell

I am doing 
P=${P//\"/\\"}

my expectation is

```
"stackoverflow" is awesome
```

changes to

```
\"stackoverflow\" is awesome
```

[edit]
The updated syntax is still not running for

```
#!/bin/sh
erroMsg=": Parse Error: line 2:122 mismatched input 'where' expecting EOF near '\"201305%\"'"
echo $errorMsg
echo ${errorMsg//\"\\\"}
echo $errorMsg
```

Output is
   test.sh: 4: test.sh: Bad substitution

Answer (score 22, accepted):

See the example:

```
$ P='"stackowerflow" is awesome'
$ echo $P                       
"stackowerflow" is awesome
$ echo ${P//\"/\\\"}            
\"stackowerflow\" is awesome
```

To escape `\` you have to use `\\`.

To escape `"` you have to use `\"`.

To escape `\"` you have to use combination of both: `\\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

almost right:  `P=${P//\"/\\\"}` - you were missing a `\`